# Java: perform for statement until given variable has reached a certain value?

Tags: java, for-loop

I want to have a `for` statement that repeats until a given `int` reaches a certain value.

For example...

```
for (int variable = 0; variable < other_variable; variable++) {
```

The problem with this is that the `for` statement will never end. It will continue to repeat endlessly. What have I done wrong?

This is my code...

```
boolean itemexist_check = false;
do {
    int i2 = m_area.m_items.size();

    for (int i = 0; i < i2; i++) {
        String s2 = m_area.m_items.get(i).returnName();
        System.out.println("Checking...");

        if (s2.contains(s)) {
            System.out.println("You take the " + s2 + ".");
            itemexist_check = true;
            player.addItem(m_area.m_items.get(i));
            m_area.m_items.remove(i);
        }
        else {
            //do nothing, repeat loop
        }
    } 
}
while (itemexist_check == false);
```

In this code, `m_area.m_items.size()` would return `1`, so `i2` would be `1`.

Comment: You'll have to provide more context, since so far as I can tell that for-loop should be just fine.  Unless you're also incrementing other_variable, there _should_ come a time when variable < other_variable

Comment: how do you set the other_variable?

Comment: @Nick Coelius - you meant "there _should_ come a time when variable >= other_variable " (notice **>** )

Comment: @CoolBeans You are 100% correct, sir.

Comment: What if s2.contains(s) is false ? Posting the requirements more will help to give a solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several possibilities:

1. you change `variable` inside the body of the loop;
2. you change `other_variable` inside the body of the loop;
3. `other_variable` is set to a large value, in which case the loop might take a long time to terminate;
4. your code never completes a certain iteration of the loop, for example:

   - it's getting stuck inside a nested loop as suggested by @Eng.Fouad in the comments, or
   - it's waiting for a lock, or
   - it's blocking inside an I/O call that never completes (or takes a long time to complete) etc.

Without knowing the typical value of `other_variable` and seeing the body of the loop it's anyone's guess.

Answer (score 0):

On a side note,

> String s2 = m_area.m_items.get(i).returnName();

is going to cause an exception if invoked in a subsequent or later repetition after

> m_area.m_items.remove(i);

is invoked, because every time `m_area.m_items.remove(i)` is invoked, the list/array loses an item and its size reduces, which is never reflected in the iteration boundary check.

Answer (score 0):

Surely it is the `do/while` loop that isn't terminating? That `for` loop cannot possibly run forever.

Answer (score -1):

You should try a

```
do {


}while(condition is true)
```

loop. However that said, you have to implement checks assuming that there will be runaway data or conditions resulting in an infinite loop. Just my 2 cents

Comment: How would that *cure* an apparently infinite loop?

Comment: Doesn't answer my question at all. How can an infinite loop solve an infinite loop problem?